# You owe yourself appreciating your work

Tags: grammar

I would like to know if a native english speaking person would find this sentence grammatically correct.

'You owe yourself appreciating your efforts.'

Thank you!

Comment: "You owe *it to* yourself *to* appreciate your efforts."

Answer (score 1):

I think a native speaker from the UK would say:

You owe it to yourself to appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Perhaps “your *own* efforts”, for emphasis.